# How can I access a List created within a class, from outside the class?

Tags: flutter, dart, class

I am a complete flutter beginner here so have mercy.

I have a class extending a changenotifier containing a list of objects.

[image: Class containing List]

I am able to add to that list and have it displayed in widgets using a provider.

[image: saving an item to the list in another widget]

Now I want to display the data from the list in a piechart, but am unable to do so because each time I call the respective functions, my implementation calls them on new instances of the class with obviously empty lists.

[image: pie chart data]

So how would I go about accessing that list from the other class?
Could I do it with a Provider as well and I just didn't try well enough?
Or maybe my approach is completely wrong and I need to start over because flutter doesn't work this way?

Thanks for help in advance.

As mentioned I tried to simply call the functions on new instances (which obviously did not work) and tried with Provider as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Images of code are not accessible, and make it harder for people to help you. They should either be augmented with the text they contain, or replaced by the text in them.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap widgets that need data from the list in a Consumer

```dart
Consumer<InventarData>(
      builder: (context, inventar, _) {
     // get data from the list
     var data = inventar.dataListe;
     // return Pie chart widget
}
```

Hope this helps.